MacOS route command fails to return data for certain IPs ending in .0
Attempting to get routes for 10.0.0.0 fails with route: writing to routing socket: not in table:
$ route -n get 10.0.0.0
route: writing to routing socket: not in table

but it works for 10.0.0.1:
$ route -n get 10.0.0.1
   route to: 10.0.0.1
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: 10.201.0.1
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING,GLOBAL>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0 

route -n get 0.0.0.0 and route -n get 0.0.0.1 both work
100.0.0.0 fails but 100.0.0.1 works
as far as I can tell, there shouldn't be a difference in how these are treated in the routing table (both should fall under the default route with a next hop of 10.201.0.1 via interface en0:
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            10.201.0.1         UGScg                 en0       
10.201/16          link#15            UCS                   en0      !
10.201.0.1/32      link#15            UCS                   en0      !
10.201.0.1         0:18:a:79:ee:7e    UHLWIir               en0   1160
10.201.0.242/32    link#15            UCS                   en0      !
10.201.255.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI                en0      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0       
169.254            link#15            UCS                   en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#15            UmCS                  en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#15            UCS                   en0      !

Running MacOS 14.7.1 (23H222)

IP addresses ending in 0 are (most of the time) network addresses and not host addresses (see https://serverfault.com/a/10989 for details) and you can't traceroute them. 0.0.0.0 is a special case and designates the default route (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94019 for details), that's why you can traceroute it.

route -n get 10.0.0.0 responds with my default route - just as I would expect yours to respond with your default route 10.201.0.1. Something odd with yours.

@jaume it doesn't need to be routable even though the linked answer indicates that it is technically routable albeit uncommon/not recommended. In this case it's being used by a fairly popular open source script from the wireguard-tools repo

@Gilby something is odd, and I'm trying to find out what's up with that!
